# Firefox not reading DTD?

Tags: xml, firefox, dtd

I have an XML file (diploma.xml) that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Diploma SYSTEM "diploma.dtd">
<Diploma>
    &students;
    &Registrations;
    &Courses;
</Diploma>
```

And the DTD looks like this:

```
<!ENTITY students SYSTEM "students.xml">
<!ENTITY Registrations SYSTEM "registrations.xml">
<!ENTITY Courses SYSTEM "courses.xml">
```

When I try to open `diploma.xml` in IE8 it properly includes all the other XML files, but in Firefox 3.5 I get a syntax error about `&students;` not being defined. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox [does not read external entities](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22942) at all (except in a few internal special cases). This is partially because it would be likely to flood sites like W3 with DTD requests, partly because it's another source of potential cross-site scripting, but mostly due to laziness, because few people use Firefox as a raw XML viewer, and few of those people use old-school DTD any more.